# BIGQUERY : value filter with where and condition

Tags: google-bigquery, conditional-statements, where-clause

In BIGQUERY,With this table i try to filter the value to get the team where first, the second and the third at the last stage ...

```
season |stage      |name              |team     | team_point   |   ranking |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2008   |1          |Italy Serie A     |Genoa    |   1          |     3     |
2008   |1          |Italy Serie A     |Milan    |   3          |     1     |
2008   |1          |Italy Serie A     |Udinese  |   3          |     2     |
2008   |1          |Italy Serie A     |Juventus |   0          |     5     |
2008   |1          |Italy Serie A     |Naples   |   1          |     4     |
2008   |2          |Italy Serie A     |Genoa    |   4          |     2     |
2008   |2          |Italy Serie A     |Milan    |   6          |     1     |
2008   |2          |Italy Serie A     |Udinese  |   3          |     3     |
2008   |2          |Italy Serie A     |Udinese  |   3          |     2     |
2008   |2          |Italy Serie A     |Juventus |   0          |     5     |
2008   |2          |Italy Serie A     |Naples   |   1          |     4     |
............................................................................
2008   |38         |Italy Serie A     |Genoa    |   45         |      5    |
2008   |38         |Italy Serie A     |Milan    |   76         |      3    |
2008   |38         |Italy Serie A     |Juventus |   81         |      1    |
2008   |38         |Italy Serie A     |Naples   |   80         |      2    |
............................................................................
```

i want this output.

```
    season |stage      |name              |team     | team_point   |   ranking |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2008   |1          |Italy Serie A     |Milan    |   3          |     1     |
    2008   |1          |Italy Serie A     |Juventus |   0          |     5     |
    2008   |1          |Italy Serie A     |Naples   |   1          |     4     |
    2008   |2          |Italy Serie A     |Milan    |   6          |     1     |
    2008   |2          |Italy Serie A     |Juventus |   0          |     5     |
    2008   |2          |Italy Serie A     |Naples   |   1          |     4     |
    ............................................................................
    2008   |38         |Italy Serie A     |Milan    |   76         |      3    |
    2008   |38         |Italy Serie A     |Juventus |   81         |      1    |
    2008   |38         |Italy Serie A     |Naples   |   80         |      2    |
    ............................................................................
```

I try this query with clause "where" but it's not good because
the where clause applies to all rows while I would like it to apply to the max(stage)

```
SELECT
  season,
  stage,
  name,
  team,
  team_point,
  ranking
FROM
  TABLE
WHERE
  ranking <= 3
```

I think i have to put a condition on the"Where" to choose the ranking at the last stage and keep the values for this teams before the last stage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
WITH a AS (
  SELECT
    team
  FROM
    TABLE
  ORDER BY stage DESC, ranking
  LIMIT 3
)
SELECT
  season,
  stage,
  name,
  team,
  team_point,
  ranking
FROM
  TABLE
WHERE team in (SELECT team FROM a)
```

Comment: i want all stages for the TOP3 team

Comment: @David I edited the query to get all stages for the top 3 teams from the last stage

Comment: And if i have more than one season and more than one league , how would you do ?

Comment: To be honest without testing/debugging it's hard to know for sure but I would try to group in the WITH query by season and league with an ARRAY_AGG for team to get the top 3 teams for each season & league and then filter in the next query just for those combinations of seasons, leagues and teams.